# How to put log file in user home directory in portable way in logback?

Tags: java, logging, logback, portability

I would like to put log file into user home directory.

How to do that in portable way, i.e. working on Windows, Linux and Mac?

Comment: Use `${user.home}` or something like that. See the docs (NB: first google answer: http://mailman.qos.ch/pipermail/logback-user/2013-May/003938.html)

Comment: If you think one of the answers below helped you, please upvote/mark it as "accepted" so that other people know it worked for you :)   (else, feel free to comment)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to [Logback documentation](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#scopes), you should use `${user.home}`, which is an environment variable present in the JVM directly coming from the OS (so it is portable):

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${user.home}/logback.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score 0):

Logging setup is really a configuration component of a system.  Your best bet will be to separate (and load) the configuration for each system.  One good way to do this is to use something like Apache Commons Configuration, this allow a traversal of a set of properties that will indicate where to find the one-off logback configuration.

We use "priority" like scheme for identifying the logback configuration file name.  Using Apache Commons configuration we specify a scheme like:

```
<configuration config-name="master-config">
<!--  start here, properties encountered in the first file would be ignored in the last file -->
<properties fileName="/opt/config/log.properties" optional="true"/> 
<properties fileName="${sys:user.home}/config/product/log.properties" optional="true"/>
<properties fileName="com/company/product/config/log.properties"/>
```

On my local windows development box (${sys:user.home}/config/product/log.properties) file will look like

```
logbackConfigLocation=C:/Users/dan/config/product/logback.xml
```

Then each system/user can configure/setup logging as desired.  From within a servlet context you can load and initialize logback.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, the path can also be anything you define as a system property. For example,

`java -Dmylog.root=somelocation ...`

And logback config can honor that property.

`<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${mylog.root}/logback.log</file>`